# How write a write a unit Test for WCF Rest Services

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, service

I need to write a unit Test for WCF Rest Services. 
This is one of the Methods:

Interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",

                                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,

                               UriTemplate = "CustomerProfile")]
    Model.Customer CustomerProfile();
```

Implementation:

```
 public  Model.Customer CustomerProfile()
    {
        return GetCustomerInfo.Instance.returnCustomerProfile();
    }
```

returnCustomerProfile Method is going to call the Database and returns Customer Profile.

in the unit test project I added the Service URL. I am not sure how to continue. if you have any site or sample would help a lot.

```
     [TestMethod]
    public void TestUpdatePasswordWeb()
    {
     string strServiceUrl =   "http://localhost:64440/CustomerRestService.svc/UpdatePassword";

 ....

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are writing is not a unit test it is an integration test.
In order to write a unit test you need to be able to isolate your class from everything else and test only its functionality.
Which means you should not use:

```
return GetCustomerInfo.Instance.returnCustomerProfile();
```

GetCustomerInfo.Instance is (I assume) a singleton accessed through the static class GetCustomerInfo and hence difficult to mock. You should "inject" GetCustomerInfo.Instance into your class in order to be able to mock it for the unit test.

I encourage you to incorporate a dependency injection library into your project and a mocking library into your unit test.

As an aside unless you are required to use WCF REST services I also encourage you to use MVC Web API for your REST needs. It has the advantage of being purpose built for REST and doesn't suffer from the everything and the sink approach of WCF.